# i want to detect previous Touch as well as current touch in the pangesture targetAction Method

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer, gesture-recognition, uitouch, gesturedetector

I Want  In My Pan Gesture Application to detect the Previous touch as well as current touch in every time targetAction  method get  call Something like the [location in View]   and [Previous Location In View]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save the touch in an instance variable every time the action method gets called.

Comment: Yes Thank You for Answering A Have Did the same And it has Work fine